# Mysql to Mysql - Hibernate replication using db40/drs?

Tags: hibernate, replication, db4o, database-replication

I would like to do Mysql to Mysql replication using [drs](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/drs/). Is it possible to do the same without storing data in db4o? I just want to use drs replication using Hibernate. Any positive/negative experience with drs?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the native MySQL replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works.

just use the #begin() call that takes 2 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration as arguments in here:
https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/drs/src/core/com/db4o/drs/hibernate/HibernateReplication.java

it will create a replication ReplicationSession which you can use to replicate data.

for example:

```
Configuration first = new Configuration().configure("first.cfg.xml");
Configuration second = new Configuration().configure("second.cfg.xml");

ReplicationSession replication = HibernateReplication.begin(first, second);

ObjectSet changed = replication.providerA().objectsChangedSinceLastReplication();

while (changed.hasNext())
 replication.replicate(changed.next());

replication.commit();
replication.close();
```